# getDerivedStateFromProps renders for each update of field in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I have a form with 8 fields.I'm setting the state of fields to the values which I get from the api in getDerivedStateFromProps.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)
{
    if(nextProps.fetch!==prevState.isFetching)
    {
        return {
            name:nextProps.username,
            email:nextProps.email// So on for 8 fields
          };
     }
return null
```

}

Now whenever I make any changes to the fields,getDerivedStateFromProps is being called and it re-renders. Is it the way how it should work or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should return object with `key:value` pair like this:

```js
 return {
   name:nextProps.username,
   email:nextProps.email// So on for 8 fields
 };
```

> getDerivedStateFromProps is being called and it re-renders. Is it the way how it should work or am I doing something wrong?

Yes, obviously. Whenever you return the new state, the component will re-render. And it's the way how react works.

Comment: In case of componentWillReceiveProps, it wont be called each time you modify the field . I wanted to clarify that.

Comment: That will do the same.